# Reading Binary Picture Data from exiftool?

Tags: java, ubuntu, exiftool

I'm working on a .opus music library software which converts audio/video files to .opus files and tags them with metadata automatically.

Previous versions of the program have saved the album art as binary data apparently as revealed by `exiftool`.

[image: exiftool output]

The thing is that when I run the command to output data as binary using the `-b` option, the entire thing is in binary seemingly. I'm not sure how to get the program to parse it. I was kind of expecting an entry like `Picture               :        11010010101101101011...`.

The output looks similar to this though:
[image: Binary Output]

How can I parse the picture data so I can reconstruct the image for newer versions of the program? (I'm using Java8_171 on Kubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to open the raw bytes in a text editor, which will of course give you gobble-dee-gook since those raw bytes do not represent characters that can be displayed by any text editor. I can see from your output from exiftool that you are able to know the length of the image in bytes. Providing you know the beginning byte position in the file, this should make your task relatively easy with a little bit of Java code. If you can get the starting position of the image inside your file, you should be able to do something like:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;

public class SaveImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        byte[] imageBytes;
        try (RandomAccessFile binaryReader =
                     new RandomAccessFile("your-file.xxx", "r")) {

            int dataLength = 0; // Assign this the byte length shown in your
                                // post instead of zero

            int startPos = 0;   // I assume you can find this somehow.
                                // If it's not at the beginning
                                // change it accordingly.

            imageBytes = new byte[dataLength];
            binaryReader.read(imageBytes, startPos, dataLength);
        }

        try (InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes)) {
            BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);
            ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert,
                    "jpg",  // or whatever file format is appropriate
                    new File("/path/to/your/file.jpg"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's kind of the issue though, I'm not sure where to begin. If I did, I could just pass the bytes to an imageview or something similar.

Comment: You can pass the output directly.  The output is a raw dump of the embedded image (usually a jpg).  Just run `exiftool -Picture -b FILE` and you can then take the output stream and treat it as the image file it is.  Or you could redirect the output to a temp file with `exiftool -Picture -b FILE >Tempfile.jpg" and then process it that way.

Comment: @StarGeek Nice. I didn't know that. I'l test it tomorrow. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it if it works :)